# Alias de campo na cláusula where do oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho um Decode no meu select assim:

```
.....
DECODE(MAT.IND_TIPO_MAT_MED,
           '1', 'BRASINDICE',
           '2', 'SIMPRO',
           '9', 'TABELAPROPRIA') TIPOTABELA,
.....
```

Preciso passar esses valores na cláusula `where`, pois eles vêm por `querystring`, e na `querystring` eu pego esses valores: `BRASINDICE`,`SIMPRO` ou `TABELAPROPRIA`. Acontece, que como `TIPOTABELA` é uma alias, na cláusula `Where` en não consigo pegá-los. Se eu pegar pelo nome do campo real, eu não tenho esses valores, mas apenas: `1`,`2` ou `9`, e na `querystring` são passados os valores representados e minha query não vai retornar nada. Preciso fazer uma inversão na query, ou seja, receber por `querystring` os valores e na hora de passar para a cláusula `where`, passar os valores reais. Como eu faço isso?

Obs: Via querystring eu recebo: `BRASINDICE`,`SIMPRO` ou `TABELAPROPRIA` e o campo aceita:`1`,`2` ou `9`. Há como fazer uma inversão?

Eu fiz um case e achei meio gambi. Fiz assim:

```
if(tipoTabela != string.Empty)
            {
                switch(tipoTabela)
                {
                    case "BRASINDICE":
                        tipoTabela = "1";
                        break;

                    case "SIMPRO":
                    tipoTabela = "2";
                    break;

                    case "TABELAPROPRIA":
                    tipoTabela = "9";
                    break;

                    default:
                    tipoTabela = string.Empty;
                    break;

                }
```

Comment: Esse segundo trecho da sua pergunta não corresponde mais ao assunto (Sql, Oracle). Convém neste caso fazer outra pergunta adicionando a tag adequada (c#, java, o que for). Blz?

Answer (score 1):

O que você pode fazer é usar um sub-select e depois aplicar o filtro:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    .....
    DECODE(MAT.IND_TIPO_MAT_MED,
               '1', 'BRASINDICE',
               '2', 'SIMPRO',
               '9', 'TABELAPROPRIA') TIPOTABELA,
    .....
) AS TBL_CONSULTA
WHERE TIPOTABELA LIKE 'SIMPRO'
```